# Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. For $0<p<\infty$, is $\left[\mu(\mathbb{R})\right]^{1/p} = \infty$?

Tags: proof-verification

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. For $0<p<\infty$, is $\left[\mu(\mathbb{R})\right]^{1/p} = \infty$?

I am trying to construct a function with the property that $\mu\{x: |f(x)|>a>0\}<\infty$ and $f$ is not in any $L^p$, $0<p<\infty$.

So I tried to use the constant function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=1$ which gives $$\left(\int_\mathbb{R}|1|^pd\mu\right)^{1/p} =\left[\mu(\mathbb{R}\right]^{1/p}.$$ Since $p$ can't be $\infty$, I think $\mu(\mathbb{R})$ is "large" enough?

Comment: Isn't $\mu(\mathbb R)=\infty$?

Comment: @JorgeFernández Right. That's why I wrote the last sentence in this post

Comment: Im sorry I can't make much sense of what you wrote.

Comment: @JorgeFernández I edited it. Is it clearer now?

Comment: yeah although I think you should remove the first sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title looks like it has some typos.

For the function that you are trying to produce you can define a function  with support on $[0,1]$. Therefore all the sets $\{x:\ |f(x)|>a>0\}$ are goind to be of measure $\leq 1$, since they are contained in $[0,1]$.

Lets partition the support into a sequence of disjoint intervals, and the define it in each of them as a constant value.

On the interval $(1/2,1]$ define it as $1$.

On the interval $(1/(n+1),1/n]$ define it as something that growth fast enough with respect to the size of the interval, like $n^{n+1}(n+1)$.

Therefore $\|f\|_p^p=\int_{[0,1]}f^p=\sum_nn^{p(n+1)}(n+1)^{p}\mu((1/(n+1),1/n])=\sum_nn^{p(n+1)}(n+1)^{p}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

For all $0<p<\infty$ this diverges because $n^{p(n+1)}(n+1)^{p}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\to\infty$.

Comment: nice :)${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I think you don't need to specify $f(x)=1$ on the interval $(1/2,1]$ since on the next line ("On the interval $(1/(n+1),1/n]$ define it as something that"), the way that you define these intervals is sufficient.

Comment: Can we define $f$ to be the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ with the rule $f(x)= \tan x$ if $x\in [0,2/ \pi)$ and $0$ elsewhere? For $f(x)=\tan x$, the computation seems very complicated.